# Can't boot from usb after installing ubuntu on mac

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my mac book air. It's the only operating system on this machine, and as I can see the system boots after loading grub.

Now, I would try other Linux OS, and as usual I'm using `unetbooting` to flash the OS on a usb. Unfortunately, it seems `grub` doesn't recognize the usb as a bootable one, and it always loads Ubuntu instead of letting me try the live OS.

I tried to use the same usb on other computers and it seems to load.